# Extracting variable name from filename

Tags: bash, awk, grep, tcl

I have a bash file:

```
agro_233_720
```

Inside this bash script I would like to use as variables the part's of it's name that underscore delimitates:

```
name= agro
ip= 233
resolution= 720
```

How can I get them ?

I tried to write:

```
name=`basename "$0"`
```

but it outputs the hole name (agro_233_720)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name=$(basename $0 | cut -d_ -f1)
ip=$(basename $0 | cut -d_ -f2)
resolution=$(basename $0 | cut -d_ -f3)
```

`cut` splits its input around the delimiter provided with `-d` and returns the field at the index specified by `-f`.

See [SLePort's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012818/1678362) for a more efficient solution extracting the 3 variables at once without the use of external programs.

Comment: This works, but isn't recommended due to the highly inefficient use of multiple external programs.

Answer (score 3):

With `read` :

```
$ IFS='_' read name ip resolution <<< "agro_233_720"
$ printf 'name: %s\nip: %s\nresolution: %s\n' "$name" "$ip" "$resolution"
name: agro                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ip: 233                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
resolution: 720
```

It splits the string on the IFS delimiter and assign values to vars.

Answer (score 2):

With `Tcl` it can be written as follows,

```
lassign [ split $argv0 _] name ip resolution
```

If your Tcl's version is less than 8.5, then use `lindex` to extract the information.

```
set input [split $argv0 _]
set name [lindex $input 0]
set ip [lindex $input 1]
set resolution [lindex $input 2]
```

The variable `argv0` will have the script name in it.